# Can I use AdSense on a free wordpress blog?

Tags: wordpress.com-hosting, adsense

Is it possible to use AdSense on a free .wordpress.com blog? I can't see any way of doing this in the configuration.

There are options to add text widgets etc, but nothing for adds?

Comment: `wordpress.com` is completely off-topic here. Also, AdSense is third-party stuff, so, off-topic.

Answer (score 3):

You can do it If you pay for premium features. With this, your blog will get **Ad-control** option .Later you do need to contact the Wordpress team using the contact form on this page [Ad control](http://en.support.wordpress.com/advertising/).

My advice is to don't expect to earn much from Adsense unless you have 1000 hits per day and are blogging about a subject where the typical visitor is inclined to click on ads. Other wise it would be a waste of your money to purchase the premium package .

Hope this answers your question :)

Comment: I have tried this option: converting a blog to premium. But I had so many issues with Wordpress support while trying to enable ads that I gave up. Well, at least reimbursement is fast.

Answer (score 2):

Adsense relies on Javascript and you can not use Javascript on a free wordpress.com blog. So you can not use Adsense. Next to that, delivering adds is something that wordpress.com reserves on it's own to do, so what you want to do might conflict with their terms of service as well.

As for any wordpress.com related question, please pose that question to their technical support as well to get an answer.